# Angular 8 - route path param's value must match list of strings

Tags: angular, angular-routing

If you have a route in angular such as:

```
{
    path: ':state',
    component: MyComponent,
},
```

Is there a way to have the path match only if the param's value for :state is in a list, ['CA','NV']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a guard to do that:

```
{
    path: ':state', 
    canActivate: [StateGuard],
    component: MyComponent,
},
```

Guard

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot, redirectOnFailure = true): Observable<boolean> {
    const providedState = next.paramMap.get('state');
    if (['WA', 'CA'].includes(providedState.toUpperCase())) {
        return of(true);
    }
    return of(false);
}
```

You can't configure anything *directly* in your routing module that would handle this logic. Guards are a great use case for this kind of thing.

https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

You could also look into NavigationResolvers, but kind of a different use case.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16211

Looks like there is a bug open for some time that won’t alllow this to go to the next route and match.  Based on the given, and my research I believe this is probably the best answer.  I am surprised angular is lacking here.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Guards are pretty solid. I use them regularly and never have had any issues...

Comment: They’re definitely solid, but it’s an issue of routing matching.  Basically, they want you to handle your own logic in the guard to figure out where to route to in this use case.  The route will not jump to the next route available and try to match.  At least that’s what I picked up from the link above.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I'm not 100% clear on how you're wanting it to route. But, yes, guards are just a boolean outcome that can prevent the activation/load of a given route. If you want to do any type of redirect, you have to do that all by yourself.